# How to get span value for multiple of the same class name using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

**Get span value using `for` loop in JQuery when there are multiple of the same class names**

I have the code below to try and get the value of the `span` elements using a loop in JQuery.

How would I be able to return: English, Hindi, ABCD, Laravel and Kannada.

```js
$(() => {
  var skil = $('.language-list .keyword-text');
  alert(skil.length);
  var skills = new Array();
  for(var i=0;i<skil.length;i++){
    skills.push($(this).$('skil')[i]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row p-3  mb-4 keywords-list language-list">
  <span class="keyword">
    <span class="keyword-remove " ></span>
    <span class="keyword-text b p-2 text-black">English</span>
  </span>
  <span class="keyword">
    <span class="keyword-remove " ></span>
    <span class="keyword-text b p-2 text-black">Hindi</span>
  </span>
  <span class="keyword">
    <span class="keyword-remove " ></span>
    <span class="keyword-text b p-2 text-black">ABCD</span>
  </span>
  <span class="keyword">
    <span class="keyword-remove " ></span>
    <span class="keyword-text b p-2 text-black">Laravel</span>
  </span>
  <span class="keyword">
    <span class="keyword-remove " ></span>
    <span class="keyword-text b p-2 text-black">kannada</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you already have got the list of elements with `var skil = $('.language-list .keyword-text');` you can loop over it like you already are doing and grab out the `innerHTML` of each element in `skil` with `skil[i].innerHTML`.

See below:

```js
$(() => {
  var skil = $('.language-list .keyword-text');
  alert(skil.length);
  var skills = new Array();
  for(var i=0;i<skil.length;i++){
    skills.push(skil[i].innerHTML);
  }

  console.log(skills);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row p-3  mb-4 keywords-list language-list">
  <span class="keyword">
    <span class="keyword-remove " ></span>
    <span class="keyword-text b p-2 text-black">English</span>
  </span>
  <span class="keyword">
    <span class="keyword-remove " ></span>
    <span class="keyword-text b p-2 text-black">Hindi</span>
  </span>
  <span class="keyword">
    <span class="keyword-remove " ></span>
    <span class="keyword-text b p-2 text-black">ABCD</span>
  </span>
  <span class="keyword">
    <span class="keyword-remove " ></span>
    <span class="keyword-text b p-2 text-black">Laravel</span>
  </span>
  <span class="keyword">
    <span class="keyword-remove " ></span>
    <span class="keyword-text b p-2 text-black">kannada</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function) to iterate over each of the spans:

```js
var skil = $('.language-list .keyword-text');
var skills = new Array();
skil.each(function(i) {
  skills.push($(this).text());
});
console.log(skills);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row p-3  mb-4 keywords-list language-list">
  <span class="keyword">
  <span class="keyword-remove " ></span>
  <span class="keyword-text b p-2 text-black">English</span>
  </span>
  <span class="keyword"><span class="keyword-remove " ></span><span class="keyword-text b p-2 text-black">Hindi</span></span>
  <span class="keyword"><span class="keyword-remove " ></span><span class="keyword-text b p-2 text-black">ABCD</span></span>
  <span class="keyword"><span class="keyword-remove " ></span><span class="keyword-text b p-2 text-black">Laravel</span></span>
  <span class="keyword"><span class="keyword-remove " ></span><span class="keyword-text b p-2 text-black">kannada</span></span>
</div>
```